# WPF Iterate TreeView right after adding to collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I have a TreeView. If it's relevant, i use MVVM and Caliburn Micro.
I want that the selected node before the clearing will be selected after adding the node. 
I added DependencyProperty to the TreeView called TreeViewSelectedItemProperty for setting
the SelectedItem property.
see the code (NOTE: i simplified the code that would be easier to read):

In the ViewModel:

```
Nodes.Clear(); 
Nodes.Add(globalNode);
SelectedNode = node;
```

In the DependencyProperty file (TreeViewSelectedItemChanged method):

```
Collection<TreeViewItem> c=GetAllItemContainers(myTreeView);
foreach (var treeViewItem in c)
{
      if (treeViewItem.DataContext == beforeClearingSelectedNode)
      {
          treeViewItem.IsSelected = true;
          return;
      }
}
```

Where GetAllItemContainers defined like this:

```
private static Collection<TreeViewItem> GetAllItemContainers(ItemsControl itemsControl)
{
        Collection<TreeViewItem> allItems = new Collection<TreeViewItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsControl.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            // try to get the item Container  
            TreeViewItem childItemContainer =  itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as TreeViewItem;
            // the item container maybe null if it is still not generated from the runtime  
            if (childItemContainer != null)
            {
                allItems.Add(childItemContainer);
                Collection<TreeViewItem> childItems = GetAllItemContainers(childItemContainer);
                foreach (TreeViewItem childItem in childItems)
                {
                    allItems.Add(childItem);
                }
            }
        }
        return allItems;
}
```

The problem is that although the tree has 4 nodes, the size of the collection c is 1.
I tried to use Loaded event of TreeView but also there the size of the collection was 1 when invoking.
The size of the collection is correct (4) only when opening the view (The dependency property method TreeViewSelectedItemChanged is invoked. i debugged it and saw that c.Count() is 4).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating a ViewModel for your nodes?

```
public class NodeViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private bool isSelected;

    public NodeViewModel(string displayName)
    {
        this.DisplayName = displayName;
        this.Children = new ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> Children { get; private set; }

    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return this.isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(this.isSelected))
            {
                return;
            }
            this.isSelected = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.IsSelected);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```

You can bind your `TreeViewItem`s to the ViewModels using a `ItemContainerTemplate`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Tree}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try that and update here. Another question, why when binding ItemsSource to ObservableCollection\BindableCollection, and one of the item is changed, although i call NotifyPropertyChanged on the collection, the item (e.g. DisplayName) is not changed\updated\refreshed.

Comment: So I did what you suggest but there is a problem. The TreeViewItemViewModel contains the Model, lets call it Item. Item is changed along the program in a lot of places but the TreeViewItemViewModel don't know about those changes so the TreeView is not updated.

Comment: If you update DisplayName and want the changes in your view, you should call NotifyOfPropertyChange as it is being done in the IsSelected property.

Comment: Consider creating a Changed event in your model and subscribe it in your NodeViewModel to update the DisplayName accordingly. If you want to bind to your model directly, consider implementing INotifyPropertyChanged or deriving your model from PropertyChangedBase.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So I'm wondering if I should subscribe every TreeViewItemViewModel (and then all the TreeViewItemViewModel's will get the message) or only the MainViewModel (and than call message.treeViewItemViewModel.UpdateDisplayName)

Comment: I would subscribe it once in the root view model and then forward changes to your tree node view models. If your question is answered, please mark it as "Accepted Answer". Thank you :)